# How get all value on li element

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm writing a c# module which uses selenium. The function will go to a web page, and I need take all elements inside a `<li>`. How do I do this?

Here is an example:

```html
<ul>
   <li>
        <a href="/test.php">Test text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Need code like this:

```
var[] query = driver.FindElements(By.Tag("li"));
foreach (var element in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine(element.Value);//Print: Test text
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IWebElement.Text` returns text that is contained between the `<li><a>text</a></li>` tags.
I also suggest using `By.CssSelector` as they are more flexible to use, for example if you would have two lists then you could get items by adding class like: `By.CssSelector("li.className")`

```
var query = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("li"));
foreach (var element in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print the text inside of the `li` elements, this should work for you:

```
var query = driver.FindElements(By.Tag("li"));
foreach (var element in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine(element.Text);//Print: Test text
}
```

Comment: The `var[]` will cause a compile error I believe, just needs to be `var`.

Comment: True enough.  Edited.